# Largest eigenvalue of a graph is non-decreasing

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-graph-theory

I am quite new to Algebraic Graph Theory. Can anyone give me a proof of the following fact:

If $G$ is a simple undirected graph and $H$ is a subgraph of $G$, then the largest eigenvalue of $H$ is at most the largest eigenvalue of $G$.

There is a very simple way to prove "If $A$ is a symmetric matrix and $B$ is the matrix obtained by deleting the last row and column of $A$, then the largest eigenvalue of $B$ is at most that of $A$" $-$ however, this corresponds only to the case when $H$ is obtained by deleting vertices from $G$.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Do you know about the min-max principle for singular values?

Comment: No idea what is this :(

Comment: In the case of adjacency matrices $A$, a simpler version is this: the largest eigenvalue of $A$ is equal to the largest value of $\Ax\|$ over all unit vectors $\|x\|=1$ (can you prove that you only need to consider $x$ with non-negative entries?).  Think about how $Ax$ compares with $Bx$ when $A$ is the adjacency matrix of $G$ and $B$ is the adjacency matrix of $H$.

Comment: @ErickWong I only cannot see why the largest eigenvalue is $\max||Ax||$ over all $x$ with $||x||=1$. The rest is now clear, thank you.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out!

Comment: Awesome.  To see why the largest eigenvalue **in absolute value** is equal to this max, you can use the fact that a symmetric matrix has an orthonormal system of eigenvectors with real eigvenvalues, then look at $Ax$ and $x$ with respect to this basis.

Comment: Then the only thing missing is to show that the largest eigenvalue in absolute value is positive (though it can be tied with the lowest eigenvalue, which you’ll see is connected to a well-known graph property).  For that I’m not sure of a simple argument besides appealing to Perron-Frobenius.

Comment: @ErickWong What about this - the trace of an adjacency matrix of a simple graph is 0 (since the diagonal entries are zeroes) so it cannot happen that all eigenvalues are non-positive (excluding empty graphs).

Comment: Ah, I remember how to do this now.  Instead of looking at $\|Ax\|$ we can characterize the highest eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix as max $x^T Ax$ over all unit vectors $x$.  Similarly the lowest eigenvalue is the min of this quantity.  The same argument goes through, showing we can restrict $x$ to be non-negative and that zeroing any entry of $A$ can never increase the value.